# tramp-default-method-alist unbound at startup?

Tags: init-file, tramp

Since upgrading to Emacs 24.5 my init file does not load.  Starting with the `--debug-init` option shows that `tramp-default-method-alist` seems to be unbound:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable tramp-default-method-alist)
```

However, I can find nothing in the online manual that suggests that this variable has been renamed or deprecated.

The exact code in `init.el` that is causing the error is as follows (except for the server name inside the first set of double quotes):

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-method-alist
     '((regexp-quote "foo.com") "ssh"))
```

My intent, if it isn't clear, is to set SSH as the TRAMP method for all servers `a.foo.com`, `b.foo.com`, etc.  (These are remote machines I have to connect to every day for my work; if I don't set `tramp-default-method-alist` and don't specify `ssh` explicitly in the string passed to `find-file`, TRAMP defaults to `scp` which is much slower than SSH on these servers for some reason.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend `(require 'tramp)` in your `init.el`, just prior the lines you have shown.

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing.  I didn't realize TRAMP wasn't loaded by default.  (Is there a way I could have known?)

Comment: No, it's not obvious. Some few Tramp variables are auto-loaded, but not all of them. I will add a respective note in the Tramp User Guide.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!  For anyone else who finds this answer helpful, here's a direct link to the [Tramp User Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/).